# Ruby on Rails question how do you stop Total time duration from appearing multiple times per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

Hi I am creating a meeting time keeping app in rails and I am having an issue with the total duration entries appearing for multiple days is there anyway to have the total appear once per day? I am using Rails 6.0.4

[image]

[image]

**my index.html file**

```
<%= month_calendar events: u/meetings do |date, meetings| %>

<%= date %>

<% meetings.each do |meeting| %>

<div class="primary">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"> <%= Time.at(meeting.start_time).utc.strftime("%I:%M %P") %></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> <%= Time.at(meeting.end_time).utc.strftime("%I:%M %P") %></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ><%= Time.at(meeting.daily_total_duration).utc.strftime("%H hrs & %M mins ") %></button>

</div>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

**my model meeting.rb**

```
class Meeting < ApplicationRecord

before_save :set_duration

def set_duration

self.duration = (end_time - start_time).to_i

end

def daily_total_duration

Meeting.where("start_time >= ? AND end_time < ?", self.start_time.beginning_of_day, self.end_time.end_of_day).sum(:duration)

end

end
```

Does anyone know any easy way to get the total duration to display once per day? Any help would be appreciated greatly

Comment: The button with class btn-warning needs to be after the `end` of the `meetings.each do |meeting|` block. It's inside the block so it appears for each meeting.

Comment: Hi Les thank you for the suggestion when i moved that button i get the below error  and none of the suggestions work for me ..... undefined local variable or method `meeting' for #<#<Class:0x00007fc8f8142198>:0x00007fc8f813b168>
Did you mean?  meetings
               @meeting
               @meetings

Comment: I'm not sure of your intent. Maybe you are looking to render the value of the `daily_total_duration` method. This method should be defined on the Meeting class like `def self.daily_total_duration` (not an instance of that class) and you'll need to pass the date to the method, for which you wish to calc the total. Then in the controller, define a variable like `@day_total = Meeting.daily_total_duration(date)` and render the value returned in the yellow button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are rendering the total duration inside an `each` block, it'll appear as many times as the number of meetings in a day. In your example, there are 2 meetings in a day, and hence the total duration gets displayed twice.

Let's first write a class method `daily_total_duration` on `Meeting` that takes a date, and returns the total duration of all meetings in that day:

```rb
class Meeting < ApplicationRecord
# rest of your code
#

  def self.daily_total_duration(date)
    Meeting.where("start_time >= ? AND end_time < ?", date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day).sum(:duration)
  end
end
```

Then let's update the view to display the total duration only once per day:

```html
<%= month_calendar events: u/meetings do |date, meetings| %>

  <%= date %>

  <% meetings.each do |meeting| %>

    <div class="primary">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"> <%= Time.at(meeting.start_time).utc.strftime("%I:%M %P") %></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> <%= Time.at(meeting.end_time).utc.strftime("%I:%M %P") %></button>
    </div>

  <% end %>
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ><%= Time.at(Meeting.daily_total_duration(date)).utc.strftime("%H hrs & %M mins ") %></button>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi 3minus1 thank you for your answer that worked when i used your code and put the button under the second last <% end %> can you update your answer and i will mark this correct ? thanks again for your help.

Comment: @SarahDuffy Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)